# Where is the best place to put a dehumidifier?

Tags: humidity, dehumidifier

I just got a 50 pint dehumidifier for my house and I would like to know where would be the best place to put it. The first floor is about ~ 950 sqft. A little drawing to show the floor plan:

[image: diagram of home layout]

When I use my wood stove the basement humidity drops to ~35% while upstairs it stays above 45-50%; temperature on the first floor is about 20-21 °C and basement about 25-27 °C.

When not using it, the humidity downstairs is 45-50% and upstairs 50-55%. Temperature on the first floor is ~18-19 °C and basement about 17-18 °C.

I'm thinking of putting it upstairs close to the stair or to put it downstairs under the hole (kind of air vent) in the floor, the dehumidifier has a fan that pushes air up.

I live in Canada and temperatures can drop to under -20 °C and currently I can see condensation in the windows if the humidity is above 50% and outside it's under 4 °C.

Comment: There are cheaper ways to dehumidify in the winter.   Outside air is VERY dry.

Answer (score 3):

Humid air rises and warm air that can carry more moisture rises.  Cooking adds moisture to the air.  All else being equal, the dehumidifier has a easier job removing moisture from cooler air with a higher relative humidity.

I would place the unit upstairs in the central location with good air circulation, nearer to the kitchen and away from any heat sources.  The location also needs to be consistently warm enough that the dehumidifier will not collect frost or cycle off on its low temperature limit.